# How to make a DC to DC step up with multiple isolated outputs?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, boost, step-up, isolated

I want to design a DC to DC step converter with multiple isolated outputs.
I need ten outputs (isolated) positive and GND.

- V<sub>in</sub>: 8 V DC from LiPo battery.
- Number of isolated outputs: 10
- V<sub>out</sub>: 50 V, 10 mV ripple max.
- I<sub>out</sub>: 50 mA per output

Is this possible?

**EDITED**
need to control each isolated output individually from 0-50V using an MCU

Comment: It seems tricky. You would be drawing ~25 watts, which translates to ~3A at the input. You would have to factor in significant heat losses while designing. If I may ask, why do you need 10 **isolated** outputs?

Comment: I need to make a smaller design rather than making 10x separate power supplies.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the outputs be isolated from each other? Can you not draw power in parallel from a single 50V rail?

Comment: I need isolated power outputs,that's the part I cannot understand how to design

Comment: You have no specifications for voltage tolerance and ripple. You have no specifications for size. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: I would suggest you edit the question to provide more information, such as where the input current would come from, what is the tolerance, what degree of regulation you need, what the output would be used for. As for isolated power outputs, you would have to wind 10 separate secondaries on a transformer. That's the simplest route I see now.

Comment: Q1. HOW ISOLATED need the outputs be ? Q2. Just to allow a DC (or AC) offset or for safety? Q3. Mains voltage isolation or 5V - 10V - ... ? | Some converters allow capacitor coupling on both legs giving OK isolation for eg 1 - 30 V say differences. You can do this at say 300V difference but it's probably unwise. | 10 x 50 mA windings is not an overly onerous task. It may take some designing depending on all the parameters that you have decided not to tell us about.

Comment: If we knew the actual spec and not just an informal subset we could probably help vastly better.

Comment: The requirement "I need to control each output independently from 0 - 50 V" just popped in comments to Neil's answer, and this changes the whole question. What other relevant data is missing?...

Comment: I think all basic data is there now I missed the individual controlling part sorry my bad

Comment: @komto909 You still haven't specified *how* isolated they need to be. Just a small offset? Mains voltage isolation? SELV?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on a reading of this specification, which implies 10 nominally 50v fixed outputs.

- Vin: 8 V DC from LiPo battery.
- Number of isolated outputs: 10
- Vout: 50 V, 10 mV ripple max.
- Iout: 50 mA per output

As the outputs need to be isolated from each other, you need at least one transformer.

As the input is unregulated, you need a method of regulation, so a flyback transformer seems a reasonable first thing to try.

You have no specification for how accurate the output voltages should be, and whether changing the load on one output is allowed to affect the voltage on another.

Assuming the output voltage is loose tolerance and are allowed to affect one another, then a flyback with one input winding and 10 isolated output windings would seem to be the obvious way to go. Each output would be individually rectified and filtered. Ripple would be taken care of by having a sufficiently high frequency, and large enough output filter capacitors. Feedback for voltage control could be taken from an 11th winding, or via optocouplers from one or more outputs. Of course the cross regulation will be poor.

If all outputs need to be independently accurate, you either need some further regulation on each of the outputs of a multi-secondary transformer (it need not be much, perhaps an LDO on each, controlling the transformer output to just meet the minimum dropout), or simply go for 10 isolated converters.

Multiple isolated converters has a 'fail soft' characteristic, that if one fails the others can keep going. Could this be important in your application?

There's little saving to be had in ganging the transformer should any or all of the outputs need to be independently variable over a wide range, so the only sensible solution for that is 10 isolated setup up controllable converters.

Comment: I need to control output voltage of each output separately

Comment: You need to elaborate on your output voltage specification. 'Control' the voltage means what? Set each at 50v +/- 1%, or control each from 0v to 50v independently, or together?

Comment: I need to control independently from 0 - 50 V

Comment: I think you'll agree that 10 outputs of 50v, which is what your question says, and 10 outputsindependntly variable from 0v to 50v, which is what you want, are verrrry different requirements. There is little to no saving to be had in ganging the transformer here. Use 10 independent isolated step up converters.